# Why does curl allow use of the file URL scheme, but not wget

Tags: curl, wget, file-uri

This question refers to curl 7.21.4 and GNU Wget 1.13.4, I don't know if the answer is version specific.

Using the [file URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) I can get local file using `curl` as such

```
$ curl file://localhost/Users/dave/.vimrc
contents of .vimrc
```

However if I try the same using `wget` I receive an error:

```
$ wget file://localhost/Users/dave/.vimrc
file://localhost/Users/dave/.vimrc: Unsupported scheme `file'
```

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because Wget has not been written to support file:// URLs. (It's [front web page](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) clearly states "GNU Wget is a free software package for retrieving files using HTTP, HTTPS and FTP")

Allow me to point to a little [curl vs wget comparison](https://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html).

Answer (score 1):

`wget` only supports the HTTP, HTTPS, and FTP protocols.

Comment: Can you provide a citation, or a reason why this is the case?