# open HTML file using cygstart and a file url

Tags: cygwin

I am trying to use cygstart to open a local HTML file in chrome. I know I can use cygstart with a URL, but the file name and file URL doesn't seem to work:

```
cygstart index.html
cygstart file://index.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cygstart simply cannot do this. Similar to how cURL supports the file protocol,
but wget does not:

[Why does curl allow use of the file URL scheme, but not wget](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10440976/#10455778)

As a workaround, you can put this in ~/.profile or similar:

```c
export BROWSER=firefox
```

then you can use it like this:

```c
"$BROWSER" file:index.html
```

[Example](//github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/20f1432/browser/.browser)